# Declaration of String type

Tags: java, string

While working with my project I've seen a declaration of a string variable like following :

```
private String compoundSourceColumnStr = "<compoundSourceColumnList>";
```

Can anyone please tell me what is actually being defined here?

Comment: you define a variable String empty, but you can use this variable only  in this method

Answer (score 3):

An empty `String` literal `""` will be initialized to that variable. `""` is called empty `String` literal.

And you can use following way to check whether a variable having empty string as value or not.

[compoundSourceColumnStr.isEmpty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

> In this case, "" is a private string literal—a series of characters in your code that is enclosed in double quotes. Whenever it encounters a string literal in your code, the compiler creates a private String object with its value.

Comment: You might want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for advice on quoting text that others have written.

Answer (score 1):

As with `byte`, `int`, `float` etc. these are all called **primitive types**. A `String` is sort of like a primitive type in the sense that you do not need to say `String abc = new String("xyz");`. It's actual name is a **String Literal**. Since Strings are used so much in Java programming, it's just a convenience method to use `String abc = "xyz"`. The two are exactly the same when compiled, however one is arguably easier to read, but even then, there is still hardly any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String compoundSourceColumnStr = "";
```

Since *default* value of objects in Java is `null` (see [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)), and since the programmer doesn't want that to be the case, he's giving the String initial value of empty string - `""`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a `string` which would hold a character array. The value is provided on the right side.

It actually is a identifier for a value. The value's datatype is `string` and the permission level is `private` which means it won't be accessible outside of its function. You can use `public` if you want to use it in other functions too. Such as:

```
public String id_name = "<value>";
```

Also note, `<>` is not required. It is just the part of the value.